# Failed to launch 'URL' because the scheme does not have a registered handler

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, browser, whatsapp

i'm trying to build a social share component with angular 11 and ionic 5. I'm using an anchor tag to call href="whatsapp://send?#text=some%20text". This works fine on devices with WhatsApp installed, but i only get the following error in the browser console on devices without WhatsApp installed:

Failed to launch 'whatsapp://send?#text=text=some%20text' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

How can i catch this error to show the user a nice message like "Sorry, you have no WhatsApp installed"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's not possible to handle it if using `href` property directly.

However, if you move this logic inside your components there are several options

**Inside application:**

You can check the app availability using [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability) i.e.

```js
let app;

if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
  app = 'twitter://';
} else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  app = 'com.twitter.android';
}

this.appAvailability.check(app)
  .then(
    (yes: boolean) => console.log(app + ' is available'),
    (no: boolean) => console.log(app + ' is NOT available')
  );
```

**Inside browser:**

1. Use timeout fallback i.e.

   ```js
   <!-- Deep link URL for existing users with app already installed on their device -->
   window.location = 'yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx';

   <!-- Download URL (TUNE link) for new users to download the app -->
   setTimeout("window.location = 'http://hastrk.com/serve?action=click&publisher_id=1&site_id=2';", 1000);
   ```

   Actually, this is the way we used in one of our web application and it worked successfully.
2. Use deep links [handler library](https://timseverien.github.io/deep-link.js/) which allows you to work with deeplinks like this

   ```html
   <a href           ="..."  Fallback  (and unsupported OSs)
      data-app       ="..."  Deep link (cross-OS)
      data-app-[os]  ="..."  Deep link (OS-specific)
      data-store-[os]="..."> Store ID  (OS-specific)
   ```

   I didn't use it before so can't tell anything special regarding it

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work if the application is run in a browser. A working example would be Amazon:
Product page -> DevTools -> select mobile device -> reload Page -> share -> whatsapp

Comment: Yeah, you're right. appAvailability won't work in the browser. My fault. Let me research a bit, maybe I find a solution

Comment: @Nico, please check the updated version of my answer where I added pure browser solutions. Hope it helps

Comment: appAvailability can only be used with native apps on iOS and Android. I think over time that it comes down to a workaround, e.g. a timer that assumes after a certain time that an action would have happened, otherwise the app is probably not installed on the device or something like that

Comment: I've told in my previous comment that I was wrong about `appAvailability`. In my last answer update I've added pure browser solutions. Did you see the `setTimeout` solution for example?

Comment: The git repo for Deep Links says it's unmaintained since 2017. But it contains some alternative links and resources in its README: https://github.com/timseverien/deep-link.js

Answer (score 0):

I use this to check if the app is installed or not.

```
 "intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=whatsapp://send?#text=text=some%20text;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp;end"
```

Comment: Some more details would be nice.